# Parsing json output and insert to a container

Tags: jquery

I have some json in this structure:

```
{"data":{"1":"file1.gif","2":"file2.jpg"}} // ... etc
```

I am trying to output it into a container div as seen here http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/:

```
  var fileUrl = 'some/path/to/files.php';

  $('a.file').click(function () {
    $.getJSON(fileUrl, function (data) {
      var items = [];

      $.each(data, function (key, val) {
        items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
      });

      $('<ul/>', {
        'class': 'my-new-list',
        html: items.join('')
      }).appendTo('#files');
    });

    return false;
  });
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="file">Display some files</a>
<div id="files"></div>
```

I think I don't know how to do the correct data extraction. 
Any hint is very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this instead :

```
$.each(data['data'], function(key, val) {
    alert(key + " " + val);
    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
});
```

This iterates over the `data` object within the JSON

[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/sREan/)